# Flutter: onTap on TextFormField only triggers after hot reload

Tags: flutter

I've got a radio button next to a text field and I want the radio to be selected when I tap on the text field to type something in it. I've put a GestureDetector on the Container with the radio and text field in it but it triggers everywhere in the container but not on the text field.
Then I've put a GestureDetector on the text field also but it only triggers when I'm doing a hot reload after tapping on the text field.
How can I trigger the radio button by tapping on the text field?
My function to trigger the radio looks like this:

```
onTap: () {
    radioOn();
}
```

Comment: try to add `setState`

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: I already added setState in radioOn()